# Not update existing records with default value of new column

Tags: oracle

I have a table with some records.

I want to add a `TIMESTAMP` type of column (`LAST_MODIFIED`) to this table. I want to set the `DEFAULT` value of this new column to `SYSDATE`.

But I want to make sure that when this column is added, existing records does not get this column value as `SYSDATE`. How to achieve this ?

Comment: show your sql statement

Comment: @Jens: ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD (LAST_MODIFIED TIMESTAMP);

Answer (score 3):

You should do it as two separate actions: adding a column and setting default value.

```
SQL> create table some_data (id integer);

Table created

SQL> insert into some_data select rownum from dual connect by level <= 5;

5 rows inserted

SQL> alter table some_data add date_modified date;

Table altered

SQL> alter table some_data modify date_modified default sysdate;

Table altered

SQL> insert into some_data (id) values (6);

1 row inserted

SQL> select * from some_data;

                                     ID DATE_MODIFIED
--------------------------------------- -------------
                                      1 
                                      2 
                                      3 
                                      4 
                                      5 
                                      6 17.03.2015

6 rows selected
```

Comment: @Apurv did not ask to prevent this. Trigger has it's own problems; say, it prevents [direct-path insert](https://docs.oracle.com/html/A96524_01/c21dlins.htm).

Comment: @PavelGatnar: where in the question did you see the requirement to prevent updates on the column?

Comment: @Pavel, what is a value of a trigger, which does not work neihter for direct-inserted records nor for any other records added simultaneously? It's a nonsense. Disabling a trigger is prohibited into production environment at all, because it breaks business logic for all users; it can be done only in exclusive mode.

Comment: @SanderstheSoftwarer we have used the trigger solution for more than 20 years in several companies, maybe it had some value... btw the triggers did not just update the columns, they reported all changes in the DB to application logs and indirectly into MQ for distribution to SAP and other systems.